# RIA HasSideEffects & IsComposable attributes

Tags: ria

Can someone explain what these attributes `HasSideEffects` and `IsComposable` for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IsComposable
```

Indicates whether the query method allows query composition. You need to mark a query as IsComposable e.x. when you want to return a class, that contains another class and does not implement IEnumerable interface. When you won't do that, you gonna get an error:

> Query operation 'XXX' cannot be marked composable since its return type
>   'YYY' does not implement IEnumerable of T.

```
HasSideEffects
```

Indicates whether the invoke operation has side effects. You want to use it when invokes an operation with a lot of parameteres. HasSideEffectAttributes enforce a POST invoke, that has no limit like GET do.